# Using java and ethers to achieve the same function, but the results are inconsistent

Tags: java, ethers.js

ethers:

```
console.log(ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(["uint256", "bytes"], ["100000000000000","0x000000000000000000000000f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb922660000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"]));
```

result:`0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005af3107a400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb922660000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`

java:

```
BigInteger amount = new BigInteger("100000000000000");

        DynamicStruct struct = new DynamicStruct(new Address("0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266"),new Uint8(1));
        StaticArray1<DynamicStruct> array1 = new StaticArray1<>(DynamicStruct.class,struct);

        DynamicStruct struct1 = new DynamicStruct(new Uint256(amount),array1);

        System.out.println("---" + TypeEncoder.encode(struct1));
```

result: `00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005af3107a400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb922660000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`

The ethers result contains two 4's, but the java result has one 4 and one 2, which confuses me

Comment: People here might not be familiar with those libraries so you might want to elaborate on what you're trying to do, what you're using etc. - Also, "The ethers result contains two 4's, but the java result has one 4 and one 2" - Where? Those result strings are really long... And finally: your Java string contains upper and lower case characters. From a hex point of view that shouldn't matter but since I don't know the library you're using, might that be an issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.